# Diferencia en parentesis while con return

Tags: c++

Por qué puedo hacer esto:

```
return (tarea->ini == NULL) && (tarea->fin == NULL); // no hay parentesis global
```

pero no

```
while (tarea->ini != NULL) && (tarea->ini != kol) // no hay parentesis global
```

?

ya que me dice que debo poner el while así:

```
while ((tarea->ini != NULL) && (tarea->ini != kol)) // parentesis global
```

quiero saber porque no vaya a ser cosa que ese return esté verificando solamente la primer condicion...

Comment: Si usas de C++11 en adelante, olvídate de `NULL` y usa `nullptr`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

La respuesta corta es: porque **while** espera una expresión entre paréntesis y el return no.

```
while ( expresion ) {}

return expresion;
```

Los paréntesis se pueden utilizar para serpara o agrupar expresiones de cualquier tipo(aritméticas, condicionales, etc.) en una misma sentencia, como sucede en el caso de la sentencia del **return**.

Por otra parte, **while**, al igual que el otras estructuras de control(if, for, switch, etc.) requiere que se especifiquen una o más expresiones condicionales entre paréntesis.

En definitiva, los paréntesis "globales" que utilizas en una setencia **while**, no significan lo mismo que los que estás usando en la setencia del **return**.

Comment: estas diciendo que al igual que con while debo hacer lo mismo siempre con if?

Comment: @Edu Según a lo que te refieras con "lo mismo".

Comment: me refiero a poner siempre un parentesis que englobe toda la condicion aunque tenga 3 && por ejemplo. Asi como entendí perfectamente que sucede con el While.

Comment: Sí. Se requieren los paréntesis en los que va indicada la o las expresiones condicionales.

Answer (score 8):

No es que haya una razón reveladora en sí (al menos hasta donde yo se), simplemente es que la sintaxis de ambos es definida de dicha forma.

El while es una estructura condicional que requiere una condición entre paréntesis para funcionar:

```
while (condición)
{
    // Cosas
}
```

El return es una sentencia que no lleva paréntesis en su sintaxis:

```
return valor;
```

Lo que si requiere es un carácter para separar la palabra reservada return de lo que viene, no necesariamente tiene que estar separada por un espacio, realmente cualquier caracter que no se pueda usar en un identificador porque entonces al juntarse "returnvalor" el compilador tomaría la palabra completa como un identificador.

Entonces los carácteres válidos para separar return de lo que viene son todos los que no sean letras, números ni guines bajos, por ejemplo:

```
return+10; // El separador es el signo +
return(10); // El separador es el signo (
return 10;  // El separador es el signo espacio
return{10}; // El separador es el signo {
return10;  // NO hay separador y "return10" se toma como un solo elemento, el compilador probablemento no encontrará dicho elemento y dará un error
```

En cualquiera de los casos anteriores es válido decír que toda la expresión es evaluada (Es decír, omitiendo el hecho de que hay operaciones en corto circuito) por lo que no hay diferencia entre usar o no paréntesis.

Comment: Ibas bien hasta el punto en que hablas de "*separadores*" en la cláusula `return`; lo que comentas no son separadores si no símbolos que modifican el comportamiento de la expresión y la manera en que el compilador interpreta cada expresión.

Comment: @Paula_plus_plus estoy consiente de que no es un término o definición oficial, estoy considerando poner una anotación sobre ello pero en el camino también quisiera reestructurar un poco la respuesta y no se me ocurre muy bien como. Lo de símbolos que modifican el comportamiento de la expresión no parece una forma muy estricta de decirlo tampoco pero la verdad no puedo estar seguro, ¿Te basaste en alguna parte del estándar para usar ese término? ¿De cuál si es que lo hiciste?

Comment: En el apartado 5.6 del [estándar](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf) indica que las categorías de *tokens* son identificadores, palabras clave, literales,operadores y otros separadores. En tu caso sólo el espacio entra en la categoría de separador. `(10)` cambia la categoría del valor y `{10}` cambia su semántica.

Answer (score 4):

En el caso del return lo que pasa es que está haciendo una operación y al final puede ser true o false

```
return (tarea->ini == NULL) && (tarea->fin == NULL); // no hay parentesis global
```

En este otro caso de while la sintaxis te pide que sea

```
while (condicion){
//codigo
}
```

si la pones de la siguiente forma no sabe cual es la operación que tratas de evaluar por eso es que debe de ir dentro de los paréntesis.

```
while (tarea->ini != NULL) && (tarea->ini != kol)
```